# How to delete `.docx` documents recursively in a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, docx

This is my code:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.docx* /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: `del /S /Q /F "C:\Test\*.docx` does what you want; `/S` deletes also files from subdirectories, `/Q` avoids prompts whether or not to delete files, `/F` forces to delete read-only files as well...

Comment: Well you got answers, but you didn't explain that you even had an issue, or give any explanation of the task at hand.

Comment: Sorry i didn't be more specific, its mu first time asking a question. Basically i just need a good code to delete all .docx documents, for clearing up my computer and other stuff. Thanks for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards with the `del` command, and `/S` to do it recursively.

```
del /S *.docx
```

If you are not executing from the directory you are deleting files in, you can `cd` to that directory on the previous line:

```
cd /somedirectory

del /S *.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a mask properly. You are searching for files with no name (which is legal). Use *.docx to say all files of any name with a docx extension.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.docx /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: the OP stated the mask `*.docx*`, but the asterisks disappeared due to formatting (remember a string enclosed within `*` is displayed in *italic* font); see the question's [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36285336/revisions)... anyway, as you stated, `*.docx` is the correct mask for the task at hand...

Comment: Thank you so much, its been great help.